# Track whether a user typed an specific "word" on an WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a ScreenLocker winform application. It's full-screen and transparent. It unlocks the screen when user presses `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P`.

But I want it more dynamic. I would like to let a user set his own password in a config file.

For example, he set his password **mypass**. My problem is- how can I track whether he typed 'mypass' on that form?

I don't want to have any textbox or button on the form. Help please.

Here is my current code-

```
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyPreview = true;

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        double OpacityValue = 4.0 / 100;
        this.Opacity = OpacityValue;
    }

    private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.P && e.Modifiers == (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.Alt))
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not simply show a textbox and button when the user presses `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P`, and have him enter his password there?

Comment: I'm not an expert in the subject, but seems to me the reactive extension framework can be useful to solve your problem. See this article  https://blogs.endjin.com/2014/04/event-stream-manipulation-using-rx-part-1/

Comment: How are you going to stop the user from pressing Ctrl+alt+del and killing your screen locking program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the typed letters in a variable, then check it on enter keydown event. Here is the working sample-

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    String pass = String.Empty;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        string value = e.KeyChar.ToString();
        pass += value;
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
        {
           //Now check the password with your config file.
           //You may have to reset the variable if the pass does not match with the config.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I think it is the most simple, though fully workable. +1

Comment: It doesn't work if the user presses some other keys and then the correct password. Give a look at the solution I provided.

Comment: @PaoloCosta Why should it? say your password is Paolo. would you be OK with someone logging in to your computer by typing aHbarthAbat**Paolo**Hargh?

Comment: you can press a key by mistake and then you can't unlock the screen for ever. There's not a textbox where you can delete your wrong chars. So you have to accept  aHbarthAbatPaoloHargh too :-)

Comment: ok, you detect the enter key and clear the password if it doesn't match, I didn't realize that....

Answer (score 2):

I think the most elegant and robust solution is to use the reactive extension framework.

```
PM> Install-Package Rx-Main
```

Key pressed are stored in a buffered observable sequence. When the buffer matches the password an action is taken (in the example it's a message box)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string password = "test";
        var keypressed = Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyPressEventHandler, KeyPressEventArgs>(
                handler => handler.Invoke,
                h => this.KeyPress += h,
                h => this.KeyPress -= h);


        var keyDownSequence = keypressed.Select(p => p.EventArgs.KeyChar);

        var checkPasswordSequence = from n in keyDownSequence.Buffer(password.Length, 1)
                                    where string.Join("", n.ToArray()) == password
                                    select n;

        checkPasswordSequence.Subscribe(x => MessageBox.Show(string.Join("", x.ToArray())));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
public partial class LockScreen : Form
{
Timer checkTimer;
string curPass = "";
string pass = "mypass"; // take it from your config file
public LockScreen()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyPreview = true;

    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    double OpacityValue = 4.0 / 100;
    this.Opacity = OpacityValue;

    // Add a keypress event
    this.KeyPress += LockScreen_KeyPress;

    checkTimer = new Timer();
    checkTimer.Interval = 1000;
    checkTimer.Tick += checkTimer_Tick;
}

void LockScreen_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    checkTimer.Stop();
    curPass += e.KeyChar.ToString();

    if (curPass == pass)      
        this.Close();
    else
        checkTimer.Start();
}

void checkTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    curPass = "";  //resets every second
}
}
```

Comment: What if the user can't type his password within one second? I like the use of timer, but I think it should be a bit longer.

Comment: he dont need to type the entire password in one second. He should at least press a key in one second

Comment: by restarting the timer, it will go again for another 1000 ms.

Comment: Opps, didn't see that `checkTimer.Start();`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I checked by typing the password in 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
private const string Password = "Foobar";
private readonly StringBuilder _builder = new StringBuilder();

private void LockForm_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    //Check if the key pressed is a control character (e.g. alt/enter et cetera)
    //and return if that is the case
    //Also make sure to reset the stringbuilder's buffer now and then,
    //if too much input is generated
    _builder.Append(e.KeyChar);

    if (_builder.ToString().EndsWith(Password))
    {
        //Correct password has been entered
    }
}
```

Comment: Its just a password, that a human is not going to memorize by keeping it a 1024 long. Too much input for a computer in this case may be more than a million..

Comment: @Sayka It's just a note I added in for the OP to consider; it's very well possible this would never become a problem, but why keep a huge string around when you'll only ever be looking at the last X characters of it?